# Android set style attribute to dynamically created ImageView

Tags: android, styling

Is there a way to set style to dynamically created ImageView?

I'm shocked how limited styling Android have compared to css...

Maybe i can somehow a blank ImageView with predefined style in fragment xml and then clone it for each dynamically required image and then change src drawable in it?

Argh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes offcourse you can set,

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style);
```

Where **R.drawable.style** is you predefined style xml file in your resources.

Comment: Well, the last thing i need then, is cloning.

Comment: Guess the only way to apply styling right in the code... It's so lame... Don't know why, but it reminds me of Actionscript in some way... :D

Comment: after above line of code give some padding as well to work fine,
`imageView.setPadding(3,3,3,3);`, now this will work fine,

Comment: http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/12/applying-style-to-views-dynamically-in.html omfg so much code for a single feature... Guess i'll do it in the code...